# How to provide application-wide authorization to HTTP JSON API for consume it within the browser?

Tags: json, web-services, api, rest, authorization

I'm currently working in HTTP JSON API for a touristic webapp. The webapp will be developed by a third-party company and it'll consume the API within the browser.

So I need for the API some sort of authentication to the third-party webapp can consume it. I've been researching a little bit about OAuth, but with this, I have a solution for a user-wide but not for application-wide authorization.

Because the webapp will consume the API within the browser(with Ajax), I'm concerned they will have to put the credentials to consume the API in the user browser.

Another solution would be place the credentials for the API in the server-side, but this don't depend on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use something similar to google's method, with a client ID and then a private key used to generate a signature.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices#generating_valid_signatures

That page has some code samples as well.